# Second Degree Equations

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I am having problems figuring out how to solve the following second degree equations:

1. 2x$^2$ + 3x + 1 = 0

I can't get factors that add together to get 3 or multiply together to get 1:

(2x  + ?)(x + ?)

2. 4x$^2$ + x = 0

I am not sure how to factorise these.

3. 0 = 4y$^2$ + 8y

I can factor this to 4[(y + 1)(y + 1)] but I'm not sure what to do after that.

4. x$^2$ = -3x

I I got x = -3 for this but the answer is x = 0 or x = -3, I don't get where the 0 came from.

I have the answers so it is really the explanation that is important to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For case 1: realize that $(2x+a)(x+b)=2x^2+(a+2b)x+ab$ and start searching for $a,b$ such that $ab=1$ and $a+2b=3$ (so **not** $a+b=3$ as you seem to think).

For case 2: realize that $x$ is a *common factor* of $4x^2$ and $x$ so that you can write $4x^2+x=x(4x+1)$

A common factor can also be found in case 3. Your factorization is incorrect.

Concerning case 4: always start with "reduction to zero". That is: realize that $x^2=-3x$ is the same statement as $x^2+3x=0$. Again a common factor can be found.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what follows after:

x(4x + 1)

How do I complete that?

Comment: I just clicked, - 1/4

Comment: If you are after solving the equation $4x^2+x=0$ then you can write it as $x(4x+1)=0$. If the product of two factors is $0$ then one of the factors must be $0$ so from $x(4x+1)=0$ you are allowed to conclude: $x=0$ or $4x+1=0$. The final solution is: $x=0\vee x=-\frac14$